# Difference between initializeApp(firebaseConfig) and firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

Tags: firebase, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am fairly new to Firebase and Webstorm, so I apologize if this is a really basic question.

I was looking at some Firebase code, and I noticed that some folks use `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`, while others use `initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`. I was wondering what's the difference between the two?

For me, I use `initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`, which seems to work fine. Here is my code for my game.js:

```
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/firebase-app";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional

const firebaseConfig = {

    apiKey: "apiKey information",

    authDomain: "authDomain information",

    databaseURL: "databaseURL information",

    projectId: "projectId information",

    storageBucket: "storageBucket information",

    messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId information",

    appId: "appId information",

    measurementId: "measurementId information"

};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

and index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script defer type="module" src="game.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Ren-Hui. You should look up and learn about named vs default exports in Javascript, that's really what this comes down to. For example, browsing [this link](https://medium.com/@timoxley/named-exports-as-the-default-export-api-670b1b554f65) might help you understand a little more about what's going on here. It's all about how you want to write the `import` statements at the top of the file.

Comment: @JeremyW Thank you for the pointer and the link, I really appreciate it! I'd like to upvote your comment, but I think that I need to gather more points since I'm pretty new to StackExchange. I'll make sure to come back and upvote your comment once I gather enough points :)